# How to use multiple if condition using eval in asp.net.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, eval

i want to use nested if condition in eval using asp.net
For example

```
<%# ((string)Eval("deviceName")) == "1,1" 
        ? "Mobile, Portal" == "1,0" 
            ? "Mobile" == "0,1" 
                ? "Portal" 
                : "None" %>
```

Comment: not sure waht you're asking can you explain more

Comment: @Moesi have to use multiple if condition in eval statement. If the result is 1,1 i have to show 1, if the result is 1,o means i have to show 2, else i have to show 3

Comment: <%# (
  (((string)Eval("deviceName")) == "1,1" ?
   (
    ((string)Eval("Mobile, Portal")) == "1,0" ?
    (
     ((string)Eval("Mobile")) == "0,1" ?
       (
      ((bool)Eval("Portal")) == true ?
       "final true value"
      :  "else value"
       )                
     : "else value"
    )
    : "else value"
   )
   : "None"   
  )
 )   
%>

I would however use a proper if and not a shorthand as this is not easy to read or follow. Hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%# ((string)Eval("deviceName")) == "1,1" ? "<span class='icon-mobile' style='font-size:50px'> <span class='icon-desktop' style='font-size:40px'>" : ((string)Eval("deviceName")) == "1,0" ? "<span class='icon-mobile' style='font-size:50px'>" : ((string)Eval("deviceName")) == "0,1" ? "<span class='icon-desktop' style='font-size:40px'>" : "-- Not Specified --" %>
```